# How to create a program to replace multiple blanks/tabs by single blanks/tabs?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to recreate a program in my textbook, with the syntax shown below. However when I add in the line for detecting tabs  [if ((c=' ' || c='\t'] (and the inverted version above , and printing only one tab at once, it shifts the entire text a few more'tabs' to the left. If I delete mentions of tabs, it works perfectly with blanks. Hope this helps.

I tried to do this question before from my book, but ended up focusing on answers from this site (https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_9) For being concise, I won't post the code that worked best, but it's the one at the very bottom of the page if you want to consult it. Afterwards I changed my sight towards a code (a part of it is listed below), which let be able to answer the Q with tabs also which which wasn't originally in the Q.

```
int main(void)
{
    int c, p;
    p = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)      

    {
        if (c != ' ' || c!= '\t')
        {
            putchar(c);
            p= 0;
        }

         if ((c == ' ' || c== '\t') && p<1) 
        {
                putchar(c);
                p++;
        }

    }   if (c == '\n')
        p = 0;
}
```

______________________________________________________________________________Another example from the site I listed, which I thought syntax was concise and interesting.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
{ if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') 
{ while ((c = getchar()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
```

---

No error messages come up, but in an instance like ' [tab][tab]hello   world
, I expect' [tab]hello world'. But somehow I get '[tab][tab][tab][tab]hello    world. It seems to increase the output by 2x including both tabs and blanks.

Comment: if (c != ' ' || c!= '\t')  Always evaluates to True

Comment: as a side note, it looks to me like you probably want your `if (c == '\n')` line *inside* the `while {}` loop, but please note that as-written, it is *outside* the `while {}` loop, thus having no effect on the input / output

Answer (score 5):

The problem is on this line here:

```
if (c != ' ' || c!= '\t')
```

Let's look at three cases:

- `c == ' '` is true. This means that `c != '\t'` is also true, so the if statement executes.
- `c == '\t'` is true. This means that `c != ' '` is also true, so the if statement executes.
- `c` is neither of those. This means that `c != ' '` is true, so the if statement executes.

In every possible case, the if statement executes.

**Proposed solution:** Re-write it as

```
if (c != ' ' && c != '\t')
```

using '&&' instead of '||'.

Answer (score 2):

Since your first if statement will always evaluate to true putchar will be called the first time and p will be set to 0.  Since p is 0 the 2nd if statement will always be true.  This will call putchar a 2nd time.  You may want to use isspace().  It will check for white-space characters.